# regular expression replace in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regexp-replace

how to use regular expression replace in notepad++ to replace all

to_char('any word')

With

'same word'::text

in a file?

For example replace

to_char(serial_number)

With

serial_number::text

Answer (score 0):

In the search and replace dialog, check the regular expression box, then:

Find what:  `to_char\((serial_number|x1|x2)\)`

Replace with:  `\1::text`

The backslashes in the find what box make the parens literal, then the parens make the text inside a saved group.
In the replace with box, the \1 stands for what was matched and will be replaced with what was matched in the first saved group.

i.e. Search for "to_char(serial_number)" OR "to_char(x1)"
OR "to_char(x2)" and replace with "(whichever one matched)::text"

Edited given new info in comments

Comment: Thanks but my issue is more than 1 "to_char(serial_number)" my file has manu case like "to_char(x1)", "to_char(x2)" etc where "x1"/"x2" can be any word with alpha's, number, underscores etc. I was looking for 1 replace-all command to do all of them. In other words can we do find what to_char\((1)\) and replace with \1::text?

Comment: @atulc Then "replace all". None of that was in your original post.

Comment: @atulc You can use a pipe symbol as a logical OR in a capture group.  Give it a shot.

Comment: can the backslash 1 or something like any a-z 1-9 etc be used in find what box?

Comment: @atulc No the \1 stands for what was matched.

Comment: ok thanks will play around to make it work

Comment: @atulc  See new edits

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `to_char\('?(.+?)'?\)`
- Replace with: `$1::text`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
to_char\(       # literally to_char(
'?              # optional single quote
(.+?)           # group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
'?              # optional single quote
\)              # closing parenthesis
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1              # content of group 1
::text          # literally
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]